# MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

Just upgraded to Entity Framework 6 to take a look. I'm using MVC4.

But i recieve this message when trying to make a controller from a model and context.

> MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Well, it means that MVC scaffoling does not support Entity Framework 6 or later. Solution: use Entity Framework 5 or lower, or don't use scaffolding

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Thought this could use some expanding :) As mentioned above ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support EF6 or higher. This means that an older EF, compatible with MVC 4 will have to be installed. To do this:

1. Open the Package Manager Console:

   - select TOOLS -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console
2. In the Package Manager Console, uninstall the current EF package by executing the following command:

   `UnInstall-Package EntityFramework -Version <version number>`

   *Where `<version number>` is the version number of the EF currently installed. 
   *NOTE: to find out what EF version is installed, run the following command in the Package Manager Console:

   `Get-Package EntityFramework`
3. To avoid potential metadata problems the providers entry in the Web.config file will need to be removed:

   - Open the Web.config file in the project directory.
   - Delete the following lines:

     `<providers>
         <provider invariantName=System.Data.SqlClient type=System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer />
     </providers>`
4. Now, in the Package Manager Console Execute the following command to install Entity Framework 5.0.0:

   `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 5.0.0`

Comment: Thank you, this post helped me. Just notes for others: you will first need to uninstall couple of packages that are dependent on entityFramework using the same uninstall command, and using "UnInstall-Package EntityFramework" without specifying the version is good enough.

Comment: I have MVC 5.2.3 referenced in my project and I still get the `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error. Do I need to install/check something in VS itself (because I guess this is a tooling error)?

Answer (score 14):

After a bit more digging

> ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or higher. Support of scaffolding of Entity Framework 6 is targeted for the next release of ASP.NET MVC.

So looks like ill wait until MVC 5 is properly released

Answer (score 10):

ASP.NET MVC 4 scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later.  Support for scaffolding will be included in MVC5.  Work around is to use EF5 for scaffolding and then upgrade to EF6.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2816241

Answer (score 1):

Workaround which worked for me to scaffold controllers and views for **MVC 4** and **EF 6**:

1. Use an EXISTING OR NEW **MVC 5** Project and copy the **Entity Data Model**
   for which you want to create your scaffolding in **MVC
   4**.
2. Add the **Entity Data Model** to your **MVC 5** DBContext
3. Create your scaffolded controller and views in the **MVC 5** Project
   which obviously works with **EF 6**.
4. Copy the generated views from **MVC 5** to your old **MVC 4** Project

---

This is a solution to generate scaffolding if you do not want to downgrade the EF Version.

For me this worked out of the box