# MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to add a controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework.

But when I try so, VS2012 tells me that "MVC scaffolding does not support Entity Framework 6 or later". 
I've read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2816241 and tried to uninstall EntityFramework 6 and install 5 in Nuget Manager Console:

> PM> Uninstall-package EntityFramework -force
>   Removing 'EntityFramework 6.0.2' from OnlinebookingAdministrator.
>   Successfully removed 'EntityFramework 6.0.2' from OnlinebookingAdministrator.
>   Uninstalling 'EntityFramework 6.0.2'.
>   Successfully uninstalled 'EntityFramework 6.0.2'.
>
> PM> Install-Package EntityFramework -version 5.0.0
>   'EntityFramework 5.0.0' already installed.
>   Adding 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to OnlinebookingAdministrator.
>   Successfully added 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' to OnlinebookingAdministrator.

But the error keeps showing up when I try to add the controller. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Has the we.config file been updated to reflect that you use ef 5 instead of ef 6?

Comment: That had been done, but didn't work initially. But I Restarted VS and needed to manually change defaultConnectionFactory->Providers to defaultConnectionFactory->contexts in the Web.Config. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: This has already been asked and solved - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19165410/mvc-scaffolding-does-not-support-entity-framework-6-or-later

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid I don't have a perfect solution to your problem, however I think I've got a pretty decent workaround:

I've had many arguments with the default MVC Scaffold-er of late, I'd recommend installing MVCScaffolding via NuGet and using the console to create anything you require.

**Steps to Fix:**

1. Install MVCScaffolding using NuGet

   ```
   PM> Install-Package MvcScaffolding
   ```
2. Run the following command via Package Manager Console replacing ModelName with the name of the model you wish to generate Controllers/Views for.

   ```
   PM> Scaffold Controller ModelName
   ```
3. Learn the basic MVCScaffolding commands

   [MvcScaffolding: Standard Usage](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/01/13/mvcscaffolding-standard-usage/)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=276833?

> You must manually scaffold your views or use Entity Framework 5 for scaffolding. Once you scaffold your application, you can use Entity Framework 6.
>
> Note This is a "FAST PUBLISH" article created directly from within the Microsoft support organization. The information contained herein is provided as-is in response to emerging issues. As a result of the speed in making it available, the materials may include typographical errors and may be revised at any time without notice. See Terms of Use for other considerations.

Comment: Link is not valid anymore